# jQuery onChange in a dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to get a dropdown to change a value of an input dependent upon the option attribute however it keeps putting undefined as the value.

```
<select class="form-control" name="ph1_plantype" onChange="document.getElementById('ph1_price').value=$(this).attr('data-price');">
    <option data-price="Arron is shit">Plan Type</option>
    <option data-price="1955">Topaz</option>
    <option data-price="2945">Pearl</option>
    <option data-price="3195">Sapphire</option>
    <option data-price="3595">Ruby</option>
    <option data-price="1695">Cremation Direct</option>
    <option>Emerald</option>
    <option>Other</option>
</select><br />

<div class="form-group input-group">
    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-gbp"></i></span>
    <input type="text" id="ph1_price" name="ph1_price" class="form-control" placeholder="Plan Price (excl interest)" >
</div>
```

Comment: Why aren't you using **option value=""** ? And you have options without **data-price**

Comment: The database is storing the data inside the option, if I use Value, it will overwrite these.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. You're not taking **data-price** from selected option, but from select directly when you're using $(this).

```
<select class="form-control" name="ph1_plantype" onChange="$('#ph1_price').val($(this).find(':selected').data('price'));">
    <option data-price="Arron is shit">Plan Type</option>
    <option data-price="1955">Topaz</option>
    <option data-price="2945">Pearl</option>
    <option data-price="3195">Sapphire</option>
    <option data-price="3595">Ruby</option>
    <option data-price="1695">Cremation Direct</option>
    <option>Emerald</option>
    <option>Other</option>
</select><br />

<div class="form-group input-group">
    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-gbp"></i></span>
    <input type="text" id="ph1_price" name="ph1_price" class="form-control" placeholder="Plan Price (excl interest)" value="" />
</div>
```

---

As a side note, you better not use inline handlers.
Better use this :

```
$('.form-control').change(function () {
    $('#ph1_price').val($(this).find(':selected').data('price'));
});
```

Comment: Also recommend not to use inline handlers.

Comment: You're right, but I was trying to solve her JS problem first. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It is considered a *bad* practice to use inline handlers. Use jQuery's `change` or `on('change'` to bind change event on the element.

```
$('.form-control').change(function () {
    var price = $(this).find(':selected').attr('data-price');
    $('#ph1_price').val(price);
});
```

---

By using `data()` to get `data-*` on element

```
$('select.form-control').change(function () {
    $('#ph1_price').val($(this).find(':selected').data('price'));
});
```

**Live Demo**

```js
$('select.form-control').change(function() {
  $('#ph1_price').val($(this).find(':selected').data('price') || 'No price available');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="form-control" name="ph1_plantype">
  <option data-price="Arron is shit">Plan Type</option>
  <option data-price="1955">Topaz</option>
  <option data-price="2945">Pearl</option>
  <option data-price="3195">Sapphire</option>
  <option data-price="3595">Ruby</option>
  <option data-price="1695">Cremation Direct</option>
  <option>Emerald</option>
  <option>Other</option>
</select>
<br />

<div class="form-group input-group">
  <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-gbp"></i></span>
  <input type="text" id="ph1_price" name="ph1_price" class="form-control" placeholder="Plan Price (excl interest)">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are referencing `$(this)` you are referencing the drop down menu itself, hence the undefined data-price. You want to traverse one more step down your menu to find the selected option.

`$(this).find(':selected').attr('data-price')`

I have put this together here:
http://jsfiddle.net/wvsLcqop/3/